# How to configure Mongoose with an already existing Mongo connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that is already working with the native Node Mongo driver (v3.0).
I'm now trying to slowly implement Mongoose in order to make the app easier to maintain. I would like to do this in a gradual way so I rewrote all the user related operations with Mongoose and the rest like it was before. **I noticed that my app now creates two connections to my Mongo db.** This is clearly because Mongoose knows nothing about my existing connection.

I would like to handle connecting and disconnecting to Mongo myself and give Mongoose a reference to the already existing connection but I can't find anything like this in the docs.

Is this even possible or will I need two different connections until my app is fully rewritten to use Mongoose exclusively?

EDIT: My app is being run as an AWS Lambda function which has to connect and disconnect to mongo on every request so having two concurrent connections per request is effectively halving my mongo db available connections. That’s why I’m concerned about having an extra connection.

Comment: Why would you worry about having 2 connections? This seems reasonable. AFAIK, there's no official way. Possibly doable by hacking Mongoose internals.

Comment: @estus By having 2 connections per request I’m effectively halving my database server’s capacity. I should mention in the question that my context is AWS Lambda so I have to connect and disconnect in every request.

Comment: Consider updating the question with this information because it contributes to the problem. Probably makes sense to create a feature request in Mongoose repo regarding accepting existing Mongo connection in `mongoose.connect`. If there are workarounds, they will likely be mentioned in comments.

Comment: @JohnnyHK read my update on the question and this will be explained. Anyway I already found my answer (which I posted) but SO will only let me mark it as answered in two days.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer to this is to do it the other way around. Just connect to Mongoose and then grab the connection.

```js
let mongoConnection = mongoose.connection.client
```